# Windows 7 Routing table issues with 2 adapters (Internal company/external hotspot)

Tags: windows-7, networking, routing, network-adapter

I've been having weird issues with setting up a routing table. Our company network recently changed, and chat programs are now blocked. My goal is to have certain IP addresses go out of 1 NIC (external), but everything else go through the internal NIC.

My main issues is that when I plug in the external NIC, I can no longer access internal sites, even if I have them routed. For example, I've done a tracert to our company internal main page. The data is:

IF 11 = Internal
IF 17 = External

internal IPs = 192.168.*.* and 10.*.*.*
internal gateway = 192.168.1.2

```
route add 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0 192.168.1.2 IF 11
route add 10.0.0.0 mask 255.0.0.0 192.168.1.2 IF 11
```

The internal NIC has a metric of 1, while the External metric is higher.

However, as soon as I plug in the external, even with these routes, I cannot access the internal network anymore.

This seems pretty straightforward, can anyone see some obvious flaws?

Comment: Exactly what kind of "External NIC" is in question? Also, your gateware need to be on the same subnet. So you can't use 192.168.1.2 as a gateway out of 10.0.0.0.

Comment: The External NIC is an iphone as a hotspot. My internal IP is 192.168.2.*, with a gateway of 192.168.1.2, and some our servers we connect to are 10.*.*.*.

Comment: Can you post your actual routing table when things stop working?